# Upgrading C2 to C3 - TypeError: Argument 1 passed to craft\helpers\StringHelper::toLowerCase() must be of the type string

Tags: craft3, upgrades

In the middle of upgrading a C2 site to C3. Everything went fine, including the step where you visit the control panel to complete the update, and now I’m at the login screen. But when I try to login, it flickers the loading icon for a second then stops doing anything. There’s a jQuery error in the console:

```
POST http://domain.test/index.php?p=admin/actions/users/login 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

web.log says this:

```
2018-08-09 11:09:37 [127.0.0.1][-][-][error][TypeError] TypeError: Argument 1 passed to craft\helpers\StringHelper::toLowerCase() must be of the type string, null given, called in /Users/darylknight/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/Db.php on line 450 and defined in /Users/darylknight/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/StringHelper.php:738
```

Any idea how I could go about debugging this? I upgraded a similar site yesterday with no issues.

Stack trace below:

```
2018-08-09 13:07:26 [127.0.0.1][-][-][error][TypeError] TypeError: Argument 1 passed to craft\helpers\StringHelper::toLowerCase() must be of the type string, null given, called in /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/Db.php on line 450 and defined in /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/StringHelper.php:738
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/Db.php(450): craft\helpers\StringHelper::toLowerCase(NULL)
#1 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/Field.php(395): craft\helpers\Db::parseParam('content.field_o...', Array)
#2 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php(1624): craft\base\Field->modifyElementsQuery(Object(craft\elements\db\UserQuery), Object(craft\elements\db\UserQuery))
#3 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php(1062): craft\elements\db\ElementQuery->_joinContentTable('craft\\elements\\...')
#4 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/QueryBuilder.php(227): craft\elements\db\ElementQuery->prepare(Object(craft\db\mysql\QueryBuilder))
#5 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php(146): yii\db\QueryBuilder->build(Object(craft\elements\db\UserQuery))
#6 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php(274): yii\db\Query->createCommand(Object(craft\db\Connection))
#7 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/Query.php(177): yii\db\Query->one(NULL)
#8 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php(1193): craft\db\Query->one(NULL)
#9 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Users.php(175): craft\elements\db\ElementQuery->one()
#10 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/UsersController.php(128): craft\services\Users->getUserByUsernameOrEmail('daryl@codeknigh...')
#11 [internal function]: craft\controllers\UsersController->actionLogin()
#12 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#14 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(103): yii\base\Controller->runAction('login', Array)
#15 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('login', Array)
#16 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(282): yii\base\Module->runAction('users/login', Array)
#17 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(538): craft\web\Application->runAction('users/login', Array)
#18 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(266): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#19 /Users/user/Sites/domain/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#20 /Users/user/Sites/domain/public/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#21 /Users/user/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php(147): require('/Users/user...')
#22 {main}
2018-08-09 13:07:26 [127.0.0.1][-][-][info][application] $_GET = [
    'p' => 'admin/actions/users/login'
]
```

Comment: Seems like a bug to me... can you send a database dump over to support@craftcms.com so we can look into it?

Comment: Just confirming this was a bug fixed in https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/8e75fccb3fddf9490a5db8b360979d374bbceb15

Comment: I have a similar issue 
Argument 1 passed to craft\helpers\StringHelper::toLowerCase() must be of the type string, array given, called in C:\newXampp\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\helpers\Db.php on line 450

in vendor\craftcms\cms\src\helpers\Db.php at line 450 – craft\helpers\StringHelper::toLowerCase(['label' => 'Waterproof', 'value' => 'waterproof', 'selected' => true])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug fixed in commit https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/8e75fccb3fddf9490a5db8b360979d374bbceb15